# Validating User Input for Letters

Tags: validation, livecode, letters

I've recently been trying to validate a user input so that only letters from the alphabet are accepted, how would I do this? I know how to validate user input for most things, but this one line of code for letters is really troubling me.

Comment: You will want to add some code to show what you have tried so far. Otherwise, this question is very likely to be closed or even deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the contents of a field with this function:

```
function validate theString
  return matchText(theString,"^[a-zA-Z]+$")
end validate
```

`^[a-zA-Z]+$` is a regular expression. `^`indicates the beginning of a string, the brackets equal one char and the expression inside the bracket determine a set of characters. The `+` means that all following characters have to be equal to the preceding (set of) character(s). The `$` indicates the end of the string. In other words, according to this expression, all characters must be of the set a up to and including z or A up to and including Z.

`matchText()` is a LiveCode function, which checks if the string in the first parameter matches the regular expression in the second parameter. Put the `validate()` function somewhere at card or stack level and call it from a field in a `rawKeyUp` handler:

```
on rawKeyUp
  if not validate(the text of me) then
    beep
    answer "Sorry, that's wrong"
  end if
end rawKeyUp
```

You could also check beforehand:

```
on keyDown theKey
  if validate(theKey) then
    pass keyDown
  end if
end keyDown
```

This method is slightly verbose. You could also put the `matchText` function in a `keyDown` handler of your field.